# scanning with scanner from a text file eats digits of a number?

Tags: java

I've created a text file named "binary". which contains binary values of numbers 0-15 (binary values are in four digits format like-0000,0001).

```
Scanner sc=Scanner(new File("binary.txt"));

int z=sc.nextInt();

System.out.println(z);
```

I get 0 as an output instead of 0000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` represents *value*, and value of `0000` (even with radix `16`) is `0`.

If you would like to read `0010` and print `16` then you need to use `nextInt(16)`.

If you want to preserve leading zeroes read it as `"0000"` String. To do so use `next` instead of `nextInt`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using an `Integer` and `00000001` is nothing but `1`.

You should be using a `String` instead.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Scanner sc = Scanner(new File("binary.txt"));
String z = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple `HungryScanner` class that demonstrates the OP's problem along with the solution offered by @Pshemo plus two solutions of my own.

I find @Pshemo's answer confusing, even though has been accepted. It gives two distinct solutions with no indication from the OP to say which is okay.

In any event, one of those answers (with `nextInt(16)`) seems wrong to me, as I understand the OP. It causes the scanner to eat up the next sequence of hexadecimal-like characters (in regex terms, something like `[0-9a-fA-F]+`) and then attempts to convert that string representation of a base-16 number into a Java `int` primitive. But that's not "binary," as the OP seems to want.

Also, the OP code `int z = sc.nextInt()` indicates that what's wanted is a Java `int` primitive, not a `String` (the second strategy offered in @Pshemo's answer). This answer is more plausible than the `nextInt(16)` one, but it doesn't seem to fit the bill - but ***something*** in there was accepted...

Part of the OP trouble might be about zero-padded output values (which also seems to be part of the thinking behind other answers and comments). In the demo code I've posted below, the `solutionByStevelWithPadding` shows how to easily generate zero-padding for both decimal and hex output. It also shows one technique to do zero-padding for binary representations - which isn't as simple as for decimal or hex (no `"%04b"` format - *sigh...*).

Since I've done all the demo testing and answer writing already, I might as well post my offerings despite an already accepted answer. Perhaps the OP will clarify, or other readers will gain something.

```
public class HungryScanner
{
    public static void originalProblem(final Scanner scanner)
    {
        System.out.println("\n---originalProblem---\n");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            final int z = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println(z + "(dec) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(z) + "(binary) = " + Integer.toHexString(z) + "(hex)");
        }
    }

    public static void solutionByStevel(final Scanner scanner)
    {
        System.out.println("\n---solutionByStevel---\n");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            final int z = scanner.nextInt(2);

            System.out.println(z + "(dec) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(z) + "(binary) = " + Integer.toHexString(z) + "(hex)");
        }
    }

    public static void solutionByStevelWithPadding(final Scanner scanner)
    {
        System.out.println("\n---solutionByStevelWithPadding---\n");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            final int z = scanner.nextInt(2);

            final String extraPadding = ("0000" + Integer.toBinaryString(z));
            final String binaryString = extraPadding.substring(extraPadding.length() - 4);

            System.out.println(""
                + String.format("%02d", z) + "(dec) = "
                + binaryString + "(binary) = "
                + String.format("0x%02x", z) + "(hex)");
        }
    }

    public static void solutionByPshemo(final Scanner scanner)
    {
        System.out.println("\n---solutionByPshemo---\n");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            final int z = scanner.nextInt(16);

            System.out.println(z + "(dec) = " + Integer.toBinaryString(z) + "(binary) = " + Integer.toHexString(z) + "(hex)");
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final String fname = "binary.txt";

        originalProblem            ( new Scanner(new File(fname)));
        solutionByStevel           ( new Scanner(new File(fname)));
        solutionByStevelWithPadding( new Scanner(new File(fname)));
        solutionByPshemo           ( new Scanner(new File(fname)));
    }
}
```

With a `binary.txt` file of contents:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

I get output:

```
---originalProblem---

0(dec) = 0(binary) = 0(hex)
1(dec) = 1(binary) = 1(hex)
10(dec) = 1010(binary) = a(hex)
11(dec) = 1011(binary) = b(hex)
100(dec) = 1100100(binary) = 64(hex)
101(dec) = 1100101(binary) = 65(hex)
110(dec) = 1101110(binary) = 6e(hex)
111(dec) = 1101111(binary) = 6f(hex)
1000(dec) = 1111101000(binary) = 3e8(hex)
1001(dec) = 1111101001(binary) = 3e9(hex)
1010(dec) = 1111110010(binary) = 3f2(hex)
1011(dec) = 1111110011(binary) = 3f3(hex)
1100(dec) = 10001001100(binary) = 44c(hex)
1101(dec) = 10001001101(binary) = 44d(hex)
1110(dec) = 10001010110(binary) = 456(hex)
1111(dec) = 10001010111(binary) = 457(hex)

---solutionByStevel---

0(dec) = 0(binary) = 0(hex)
1(dec) = 1(binary) = 1(hex)
2(dec) = 10(binary) = 2(hex)
3(dec) = 11(binary) = 3(hex)
4(dec) = 100(binary) = 4(hex)
5(dec) = 101(binary) = 5(hex)
6(dec) = 110(binary) = 6(hex)
7(dec) = 111(binary) = 7(hex)
8(dec) = 1000(binary) = 8(hex)
9(dec) = 1001(binary) = 9(hex)
10(dec) = 1010(binary) = a(hex)
11(dec) = 1011(binary) = b(hex)
12(dec) = 1100(binary) = c(hex)
13(dec) = 1101(binary) = d(hex)
14(dec) = 1110(binary) = e(hex)
15(dec) = 1111(binary) = f(hex)

---solutionByStevelWithPadding---

00(dec) = 0000(binary) = 0x00(hex)
01(dec) = 0001(binary) = 0x01(hex)
02(dec) = 0010(binary) = 0x02(hex)
03(dec) = 0011(binary) = 0x03(hex)
04(dec) = 0100(binary) = 0x04(hex)
05(dec) = 0101(binary) = 0x05(hex)
06(dec) = 0110(binary) = 0x06(hex)
07(dec) = 0111(binary) = 0x07(hex)
08(dec) = 1000(binary) = 0x08(hex)
09(dec) = 1001(binary) = 0x09(hex)
10(dec) = 1010(binary) = 0x0a(hex)
11(dec) = 1011(binary) = 0x0b(hex)
12(dec) = 1100(binary) = 0x0c(hex)
13(dec) = 1101(binary) = 0x0d(hex)
14(dec) = 1110(binary) = 0x0e(hex)
15(dec) = 1111(binary) = 0x0f(hex)

---solutionByPshemo---

0(dec) = 0(binary) = 0(hex)
1(dec) = 1(binary) = 1(hex)
16(dec) = 10000(binary) = 10(hex)
17(dec) = 10001(binary) = 11(hex)
256(dec) = 100000000(binary) = 100(hex)
257(dec) = 100000001(binary) = 101(hex)
272(dec) = 100010000(binary) = 110(hex)
273(dec) = 100010001(binary) = 111(hex)
4096(dec) = 1000000000000(binary) = 1000(hex)
4097(dec) = 1000000000001(binary) = 1001(hex)
4112(dec) = 1000000010000(binary) = 1010(hex)
4113(dec) = 1000000010001(binary) = 1011(hex)
4352(dec) = 1000100000000(binary) = 1100(hex)
4353(dec) = 1000100000001(binary) = 1101(hex)
4368(dec) = 1000100010000(binary) = 1110(hex)
4369(dec) = 1000100010001(binary) = 1111(hex)
```

PS - In my demo I'm *not* closing the created `Scanner` objects. ***It's just a demo!!*** 8>P